# Self Join issue, not receiving any result

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run query where I would compare same accounts with different time stamps, I have run this query (similar, with real accounts but I am not getting any result back. Please help.

```
    select  t1.number , t1.created, t1.comment, t2.number , t2.created,     
    t2.comment from [aaa].[dbo].[t_table]  t1 inner join 
    (select number , created, comment from [aaa].[dbo].[table]
where created > '2017-07-06 12:00:00.000' 
    and number in (1,2,3,4,5)) t2
    on t1.number = t2.number
    where t1.created >= '2017-07-06 11:00:00.000' and 
    t1.created < '2017-07-06 12:00:00.000' and t1.number in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: What does this return: select number , created, comment from [aaa].[dbo].[t_table]
where created > '2017-07-06 12:00:00.000' 
    and number in (1,2,3,4,5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
t1 inner join 
    (select number , created, comment from [aaa].[dbo].[table]
where created > '2017-07-06 12:00:00.000'
```

gets rows after noon but this condition:

```
t1.created < '2017-07-06 12:00:00.000'
```

gets rows before noon.  They are mutually exclusive.  No rows were created both *before* and *after* noon.

Based on what you entered in the other part of the query, perhaps you mean:

```
t1 inner join 
    (select number , created, comment from [aaa].[dbo].[table]
where created > '2017-07-06 11:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Yes I meant <created > '2017-07-06 11:00:00.000' > is there are solution? I want to pull all accounts with different time stamp and compare.